How do I solve solution to the kotlin code?
My Kotlin code has an error every time I compile it.
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.alan.bottombarjc"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.alan.bottombarjc"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
}
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    languageVersion = "1.9"
}

org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'compileKotlin' not found in project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.named(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.named(DefaultTaskCollection.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.named(DefaultTaskCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectCollectionExtensionsKt.provideDelegate(NamedDomainObjectCollectionExtensions.kt:410)
    at Build_gradle.<init>(build.gradle.kts:74)`

File invalidate cache and restart and I tried to update android but it doesn't work.

Please don't post pictures of code.  Post the code itself.

Please try the following inside android block
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.9"
    }
}

and remove
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
  compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
  languageVersion = "1.9"
}

I hope this will fix your problem.
